# Use the Chernoff Inequality to bound a probability.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, binomial-distribution

> A coin is equally likely to be either $B_{1/3}$ (Bernoulli distributed with $p=1/3$) or $B_{2/3}$. To figure out the bias, we toss the coin 99 times and declare $B_{1/3}$ if the number of heads is less than 49.5 and $B_{2/3}$ otherwise. Bound the error probability using the Chernoff bound.

The Chernoff inequality or bound states: $P(X\geq a) = P(e^{tX}\geq e^{ta}) \leq \frac{E[e^{tX}]}{e^{ta}}$

In the special case of a binomial distribrution the lower bound of the Chernoff inequality is given by: $P(X\leq(1-\delta)\mu) = e^{-\frac{\delta^2}{2}\mu}$

From the question I understand that we are looking for the bound prob that

- (1) choosing $B_{1/3}$ is wrong if we see 49.5 or less heads after the 99 tosses.
- (2) Or we choose $B_{2/3}$ if we see 49.5 or more heads after the 99 tosses.

To calculate the first part (1):
I tried using the binomial case of the Chernoff inequality. First, calculating $\delta$

$$
P(X\leq(1-\delta)\mu) = P(49.5 \leq (1-\delta)E(X_{2/3}))\\
E(X_{2/3})=\frac{2}{3}99 = 66\\ 
\delta = 1-\frac{49.5}{66} = 0.25\\
$$
Then I plugged delta into the inequality to get the lower bound probability:
$$
P(X\leq(1-0.25)66)\leq e^{-\frac{0.25^2}{2}66} =  0.1271
$$

for the second part (2):
first we need to use the binomial Chernoff upper bound inequality, which is: $P(X\geq(1+\delta)\mu) = e^{-\frac{\delta^2}{2+\delta}\mu}$

Again I calculte delta:
$$
P(X\geq(1+\delta)\mu) = P(49.5 \geq (1-\delta)E(X_{1/3}))\\
E(X_{1/3})=\frac{1}{3}99 = 33\\ 
\delta = \frac{49.5}{33}-1 = 0.5\\
$$
Then I plugged delta into the inequality to get the upper bound probability:
$$
P(X\geq(1+0.5)33)\leq e^{-\frac{0.5^2}{2.5}33} =  0.03688
$$

Finally, I add both upper and lower bound $P(wrong) = P(X\geq49.5)+P(X\leq49.5) = 0.1640189 $

However, this answer is wrong, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Maybe is the interpretation of the question? Any help or hint would be very appreciated!

Comment: It would be nice if you defined your notation. Is $B_{1/3}$ notation for Bernoulli$(1/3)$? And I have never heard of this Chernoff Inequality even though I'm a Statistician.. so it would be helpful if you stated the Chernoff Inequality.

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks for the edit and further hints. I have tried to complete the question, please let me know if it mekes sense to you, otherwise I will try to make it clearer.

Comment: An error occurs if we guess 1/3 but it is really 2/3, or if we guess 2/3 and it is really 1/3. It looks like you are only considering one type of error. By near-symmetry I would not expect the two types of errors to have significantly different probabilities. There are also minor deviations possible if you use 49.5 in the bound, or 49, since $P[X\leq 49.5]=P[X\leq 49]$. Further, these are bounds and so they differ from the exact answer.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for your comment. I tried adding both bound but the answer is still wrong. I edited the question to include the upper bound. Do you have any more ideas. Or did I misinterpret your comment? Thanks!